# Why was Dawn sent to Buffy and not the "current" slayer?

Tags: buffy-the-vampire-slayer

When Buffy died in S1E12 - Prophecy Girl (she was killed by the master), she was replaced by another Slayer and the strength was transmitted to another. So, when the monks created Dawn to contain the key and sent it to the Slayer, why was it sent to Buffy and not Faith?

An out-of-universe explanation is obvious: there would've been no story if Dawn had been sent to Faith. So, I am looking for an in-universe explanation why Dawn was sent to the old Slayer and not the current one.

Comment: I don't think the strength was *transmitted to* Faith, so much as *activated* (see season 7). It also calls into question whether there has to be *the* Slayer, rather than there is usually only one *active* Slayer at a time. Word of mouth being what it seems to be in the supernatural community, it's probably widely known that Buffy is the "real" Slayer.

Comment: @chepner Activated is a way better word, ty.

Comment: Buffy wasn't *replaced* as slayer, nor was her strength transmitted to someone else. She remains a vampire slayer (complete with prophetic duties), just not carrying the *line of the Slayer* in the event of her death.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Key was sent to Buffy *intentionally*. The monks didn't just do a magical spell that locates the nearest slayer and send her a sister, but in fact systematically rebuilt the memories and reality of the people around Buffy to create an emotional and physical bond between the two. Additionally, they seem to be unaware or don't care that there's a second slayer floating around, noting that Faith is (at this point in the show) living a rootless existence and is in no position to provide a safe environment for anyone else.

> **BUFFY:** *You put that in my house?*
> **MONK:** *We knew **the Slayer** would protect.*
> **BUFFY:** *My memories... my mom's?*
> **MONK:** ***We built them.***
>
> <sub><sup>[BTVS: No Place Like Home](https://buffy.fandom.com/wiki/No_Place_Like_Home)</sup></sub>

Out of universe, the character of Faith was entirely absent from Seasons 5 and 6 of the show. Giving her 'The Key' would have mean having Dushku back in the show at a time when she was committed to several film projects.